# Directives in markdown header-includes being ignored

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm creating a document using bookdown. The primary target is printer pdf output so I want to get hyperlinks as footnotes. To do this I added the following lines to the YAML header in index.Rmd.

```
header-includes:
  - \let\oldhref\href 
  - \renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnote{\url{#1}}}
```

This has absolutely no effect. If instead I add the following to the preamble.tex file in the project directory I get the behaviour I want.

```
\let\oldhref\href 
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnote{\url{#1}}}
```

I have the same problem attempting to include packages using the header-includes as well. They just don't seen to get used and I get errors in the document build. Again, adding the \usepackage into preamble.tex works.

So I'm obviously missing something where header-includes is concerned but I don't know what it is.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

To reproduce this (at least the \usepackage version of the problem) using the latest version of RStudio on Windows with the latest version of bookdown from CRAN create a new Bookdown project using RStudio and make sure you have the package placeins installed in your LaTex environment then edit the supplied header in index.Rmd to give this:

```
--- 
title: "A Minimal Book Example"
author: "Yihui Xie"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{placeins}
bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
description: "This is a minimal example of using the bookdown package to write a book. The output format for this example is bookdown::gitbook."
---
```

In the file 01-intro.Rmd add this immediately after the code to produce the Figure:

```
\FloatBarrier
```

Use The Build Book tab to build a PDF book and you will see the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.179 \FloatBarrier
```

Placing the \usepackage statement in preamble.tex removes the error.

Comment: Just to make sure we're looking at it right, can you provide a complete skeleton r-markdown file including this? Please include (at least) one or two instances of using this new code, but we don't necessarily need sample data or other unrelated code. Thanks!

Comment: @r2evans I've added some details on how to reproduce the problem. Is this enough clarification?